# REST-ful webservice @Context Injection always returns null

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, restful-architecture, javax.ws.rs

I am creating my first Restful web service with Embedded Jetty with authentication and authorization and I have a filter in which I would like to inject a user object (Employee) which then I can retrieve in a service bean using ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext() the @Context annotation, but whatever I try the object always is null. I would appreciate any kind of help.

```
@PreMatching
public class AuthenticationHandler implements ContainerRequestFilter {


@Inject private PxCredentialService credentialService;


@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    Response faultresponse = createFaultResponse();

    String authorization = requestContext.getHeaderString("Authorization");
    String[] parts = authorization.split(" ");
    if (parts.length != 2 || !"Basic".equals(parts[0])) {
        requestContext.abortWith(createFaultResponse());
        return;
    }

    String decodedValue = null;
    try {
        decodedValue = new String(Base64Utility.decode(parts[1]));
    } catch (Base64Exception ex) {
        requestContext.abortWith(createFaultResponse());
        return;
    }
    String[] namePassword = decodedValue.split(":");
    Employee emp = credentialService.getCredentialsByLoginAndPass(namePassword[0], namePassword[1], true);
    if ( emp != null) {
    ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(Employee.class, emp);
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("False Login");//requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(401).build());
    }
```

}

```
@Path( "/people" )
public class PeopleRestService implements credentials {
@Inject private PeopleService peopleService;
@Inject private GenericUserRightsUtil genericUserRightsUtil;


@Produces( { "application/json" } )
@GET
public Collection<Person> getPeople(@Context Employee emp) {

    Employee emp = (Employee)crc.getProperty("Employee");

    return peopleService.getPeople( page, 5 );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my understanding, you want an easy way to identify the user who is performing the request in your resource methods. Have you ever considered setting a [`SecurityContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) with a [`Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) for the request?

In your filter, if the user credentials as valid, do the following

```java
final SecurityContext currentSecurityContext = requestContext.getSecurityContext();
requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {

        return new Principal() {

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return username;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return currentSecurityContext.isSecure();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return "Basic";
    }
});
```

Your resource method will be like:

```java
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response foo(@PathParam("id") Long id, 
                    @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    ...
}
```

To get the [`Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html), use:

```java
Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
String username = principal.getName();
```